# syntax error in the code in the line break list due to the input, how do you adjust this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, helper

Syntax error in multiple lines of code between the input and the list also.

````py
    Import math 
    o = " What operation do you want to use :\n\

    1. Add\n\ 
    2. Subtract\n\
    3. Multiply\n\
    4. Divide\n\
    5. Square the first number\n\
    6. Square the second number\n\
    7. Calculate the power of the first number to the second number\n\
    8. Square root the first number\n\
    9. Square root the second number\n\"

    n1 = int(input(" Enter the first number: "))

    n2 = int(input(" Enter the second number: "))

    print(o) 

    oc = int(input("Enter the operation you have chose:"))

    if oc == 1: 
     print(n1 + n2)

    elif oc == 2:
        print (n1 - n2)

    elif oc == 3:
        print(n1 * n2)

    elif oc == 4:
        print(n1 / n2)

    elif oc == 5:
        print(n1**2)

    elif oc == 6:
        print(n2*2)
```this does not work properly```
    elif oc == 7:
        print(n1**n2)

    elif oc == 8:
        print(math.sqrt(n1))

    elif oc == 9:
        print(math.sqrt(n2))
````

The code does not process the input correctly, it would be easier to use an array or a list. Or even use numpy and use a text files. How would

Comment: also in my code the prints are ordered properly

Comment: Just looking at the text coloring done by the code formatter, it looks like you have an unterminated string constant somewhere. You need an extra quote mark!

Answer (score 3):

multiline strings in python are delimited by `'''`.

you should write:

```
o = ''' What operation do you want to use :

1. Add
2. Subtract
3. Multiply
4. Divide
5. Square the first number
6. Square the second number
7. Calculate the power of the first number to the second number
8. Square root the first number
9. Square root the second number'''
```

the rest seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

You should use three quotes if you are going to have a multi line string like that also to preform a line break that is just \n. Hope I helped.

```
import math 
o = """ What operation do you want to use :\n

1. Add\n
2. Subtract\n
3. Multiply\n
4. Divide\n
5. Square the first number\n
6. Square the second number\n
7. Calculate the power of the first number to the second number\n
8. Square root the first number\n
9. Square root the second number\n"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You've left an extra `\` at the end of this line:

```
9. Square root the second number\n\"
```

This escapes the `"` and causes the string to not be terminated.

It's better to use triple quotes around the multiline string as @hiro suggests

Answer (score 0):

Except the multiline string, started with ''' in place of '', everything is ok. Now you should try to get less lines of code. You learn when you optimize your working scripts.